# How to delete a row from an excel using JXL

Tags: java, jxl

I am new to JXL and have worked on read and write of Excel files. But I could not find a function which would delete a row after I successfully read that row and move to the next.

Code logic:
If(readrow() == true)
{
  deleteRow();
}

Is there any example available? If there is no delete function can I copy the row to a new sheet and after all the rows are complete I would rename this sheet as the old sheet and remove the old sheet?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

JXL does have a delete/remove row function... check [this link](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableSheet.html#removeRow%28int%29) for help

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){

if(doneWithRow){
sheet.removeRow(i);
}
}
```

the code example is not much but should get you started.

Comment: Weird that in a loop that contains 15 rows, it only delete 5