# Delete Row from jxl excel sheet

Tags: jxl

How do I delete an entire row from a jxl excel sheet ? I can find the row by column contents.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885587/how-to-delete-a-row-from-an-excel-using-jxl) but for my case I have only the jxl sheet not the `WritableSheet`

-Amit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a row from an Existing Excel Sheet using JXL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892270/how-to-delete-a-row-from-an-existing-excel-sheet-using-jxl)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = endLine -1 ; i >= startLine -1 ; i--) { wSheet.removeRow(i);}
```

Remember that the JXL will elevate all the following lines when this line is deleted, so try to delete lines backwards in order to avoid the alternative deletion.